# Angular momentum vs torque/moment of a force

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, torque

What is the difference between

M$_A$ ($\overrightarrow {M}$)=$\overrightarrow {AM}$$\times$$\overrightarrow {F}$

And

$\overrightarrow {L_A}$= $\overrightarrow {AM}$$\times$$m$$\overrightarrow {V(M)}$

Now I understand that one is the moment of a force while the other is for a point.
But how can it turn around the point without a force?
And the momentum of the forceful itself turns around a point? I believe that I have deep problems in the understanding of momentum. I tried going back to my old textbooks but nothing really helped… :”)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is M torque and is L angular momentum?   Please clarify your relationships.

Comment: @John Darby yes

Comment: Cross is written using the multiplication symbol \times.

Answer (score 0):

Torque $\vec M$ is the first moment ("angular equivalent") of force $\vec F$ and angular momentum $\vec L$ is the first moment ("angular equivalent") of momentum $\vec p$.  Just as force changes momentum, torque changes angular momentum.  With no force momentum is constant, with no torque, angular momentum is constant; specifically, $\vec F = {d \vec p \over dt}$ and $\vec M = {d \vec L \over dt}$.